# org-mode source code block using minted doesn't indent exported ruby correctly

Tags: org-mode, org-export, beamer

I am using org-mode to make a Beamer LaTeX presentation, which then gets rendered to PDF.

Here is the part I am having trouble with:

```
* Vectors in Ruby (components)
- a Vector can be added to another vector
- a Vector can be multiplied by a scalar
#+begin_src ruby
class Vector
  def +(vector)
    Vector.new(components.zip(vector.components).map {|(vi,wi)| vi+wi })
  end

  def *(scalar)
    Vector.new(components.map{|c| scalar*c })
  end
end
#+end_src
```

When I run org-export-dispatch and render to PDF, here's what the methods look like:

[image]

I checked in the intermediate .tex file and the `Vector` lines have a tab indentation instead of space. It is inside a `\begin{minted}` block.

How can I fix this indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to ensure that source code formatting is preserved in exports from Org-mode, set the variables `org-src-preserve-indentation` to 't', and `indent-tabs-mode` to 'nil' using **customize-variable**.